# Heat-map-style plot showing modal value for grid region (via stat_summary_2d?)

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a set of 2D points with category labels, and want to visualize which category dominates each cell of a grid super-imposed over the 2D plane.

I imagined I would be able to use `stat_summary_2d` with a function that selects the most frequent value as shown below, but I got different plots for three variations that should be identical except for the legend labels.

Am I misusing `stat_summary_2d`? Is there a better way to generate this plot?

```
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(12345)
x = runif(1000)
y = runif(1000)
lab = rep(c("red", "blue", "green", "yellow"), 250)

df = data.frame(x=x, y=y, lab=factor(lab, labels=c("red", "blue", "green", "yellow")))
df$val = as.numeric(df$lab)

#Attempt 1
ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y)) + 
  stat_summary_2d(aes(z=lab), 
                  fun=function(z) names(which.max(table(z))), 
                  binwidth=.1)

#Attempt 2
ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y)) + 
  stat_summary_2d(aes(z=val), 
                  fun=function(z) names(which.max(table(z))), 
                  binwidth=.1)

#Attempt 3
ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y)) + 
  stat_summary_2d(aes(z=as.numeric(lab)), 
                      fun=function(z) names(which.max(table(z))),
                      binwidth=.1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `group = 1` to Attempt 1 & you'll see the same distribution of panels as the subsequent two attempts.

Specify the fill palette appropriately, & all three will look the same:

```
library(ggplot2)

#Attempt 1
p1 <- ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y, group = 1)) + 
  stat_summary_2d(aes(z=lab), 
                  fun=function(z) names(which.max(table(z))), 
                  binwidth=.1) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("red" = "red",
                               "blue" = "blue",
                               "green" = "green",
                               "yellow" = "yellow"),
                    breaks = c("red", "blue", "green", "yellow")) +
  ggtitle("Attempt 1") + theme(legend.position = "bottom")

#Attempt 2
p2 <- ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y)) + 
  stat_summary_2d(aes(z=val), 
                  fun=function(z) names(which.max(table(z))), 
                  binwidth=.1) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("red", "blue", "green", "yellow")) +
  ggtitle("Attempt 2") + theme(legend.position = "bottom")

#Attempt 3
p3 <- ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y)) + 
  stat_summary_2d(aes(z=as.numeric(lab)), 
                  fun=function(z) names(which.max(table(z))),
                  binwidth=.1) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("red", "blue", "green", "yellow")) +
  ggtitle("Attempt 3") + theme(legend.position = "bottom")

gridExtra::grid.arrange(p1, p2, p3, nrow = 1)
```

[image: combined plot]

**Explanation**: If you examine the underlying data of the first plot, you'll notice that there are 379 rows of data, each corresponding to one tile in the heatmap. If we total up the number of different colours within each bin, we'll get 379 as well, so there's in fact multiple tiles at each bin position. (In contrast, the underlying data for the second and third plots have 100 rows each.)

Based on this, we know that ggplot had interpreted each factor level in "lab" to be a separate group, and performed `stat_summary_2d()` separately for each level. Adding `group = 1` to the aesthetic mapping forced all levels to be considered together.

```
p1.original <- ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y)) + 
  stat_summary_2d(aes(z=lab), 
                  fun=function(z) names(which.max(table(z))), 
                  binwidth=.1)

View(layer_data(p1.original))
```